# Compound Adjectives and -ed

Tags: adjectives, hyphenation, compounds

A colleague asked me this question, and I couldn't come up with an answer that satisfied him, so I'm wondering if anyone can help:

Why does *a man with a short temper* become *a short-tempered man*?
In other words, why do you need the *-ed* at the end?

Are there any special rules for this?

Comment: Great question. If one called him "short-temper man", it sounds like a title (a super-hero name). We seem to need an adjective instead of a noun.

Comment: There really doesn't seem to be a neat answer to this question, but this might help make it a bit clearer.  Thanks!

Comment: related [Do adjectives ending in -ed derive from words that were once used as verbs?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2212/do-adjectives-ending-in-ed-derive-from-words-that-were-once-used-as-verbs)

Comment: Great question. These have been around a long time — Shakespeare talked about *"green-eyed jealousie"* — so maybe they're the remnant of some Middle English grammar which is obsolete except in this type of adjective.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*This must not be taken as a definitive answer. Only hints too long to fit in a comment.*

**A** - In order to form a compound adjective of the type adj+noun-ed, I'd say:

1- the noun should be able to transform into a reasonably comprehensible ed-adjective

- temper → tempered (s.o. or sth with a temper, seems OK)
- chair (n) → *chaired (doesn't seem to make sense)

2- the adjective in the first part of the compound word must fit with the noun-ed adjective.

- a *blue-eyed boy* seems OK
- a *blue-tempered* boy doesn't seem to make sense

**B**- I've just gone back to an [academic paper](http://palimpsestes.revues.org/118) I'd read a while ago exploring compound adjectives and in particular "the noun + -ed structure".

Here's a paragraph from this paper, it doesn't really answer the "why" in your question, but points toward a possible answer.
(Paper's in French, translation mine).

> Many linguists have pointed out that this type of compound adjectives (adj+noun-ed) is mostly used when describing a physical (*blue-eyed*) or mental (*bad-tempered*) characteristic. This physical characteristic doesn't only apply to people but can be found in animals (*short-winged*, *red-tailed*) or objects (*red-roofed*, *sharp-pointed*). Assuming that the adj+noun-ed compound adjective gives a definitory attribute to the noun, some linguists and grammarians will be inclined to refuse compound adjectives whose first word would express the point of view of the speaker.

Further on in this paper the author compares the compound noun "middle-age" to the adjective "middle-aged". Could we imagine short-temper as a possible noun? Then could we say the -ed suffix differentiates the noun from the adjective?

A question [*with/without “-ed” for the compound adjectives formed by “adj.+noun”?*](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134192/with-without-ed-for-the-compound-adjectives-formed-by-adj-noun#comment277590_134192) had been asked on english.se, and thanks to FumbleFingers for pointing out to John Lawler's comment on the disappearance of "ed" in spoken (and consequently written form) English.

Comment: Chair can also be a verb; "She chaired the department for many years". *A chaired meeting* is therefore possible.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: exactly, that's what the "(n)" after chair means, so that a "perfectly-chaired assembly" could not be taken as an example.  But feel free to take another noun...  boy→boyed doesnt work either for me but people→peopled works.

Comment: I see, I hadn't noticed the (n); the phrase you give as an example might not be idiomatic, but it's not as nonsensical as "blue-tempered". Notwithstanding that bit, I like your answer!

Comment: @Mari-LouA: "Short-lived" adventure: second part of the compound is derived from verb "live" and not noun "life".  "Boyhood" is a compound noun not an adjective. Yes, "people" and "man", and "crowd" (others probably) work because they can be verbs.

Comment: What about the expression a "short-lived adventure"? No people, animals or objects involved there. I was referring to the noun, adventure. I was thinking aloud to myself when I read the quoted article you translated. And then I suppose we move onto [noun adjuncts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noun_adjunct). It's a vast topic.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: I agree adventure is a noun, but "short-lived" is "adj+V-ed" and not "adj+noun-ed" (like "blue-eyed" for example) so it doesn't fit into the scope of possible compounds referred to in the quoted paragraph, does it?

Comment: Such a good answer.  And your paper (errr, the one to which you make reference) is actually available online, which is even better.

Comment: 'Short-tempered' is widely used, as a Google scan and personal experience might indicate. 'Bad-tempered' surely would not be queried by anybody, and surely it 'express[es] the point of view of the speaker'?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: I'm not disputing that, I mean I entirely agree, and I assume the academic I was quoting as well. I understand her remark as scientific honesty to cover all points of view.

Comment: Zeki Hamawand discusses semantic groups of [compound adjectives](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=a9Rj18gtf5kC&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=10.2+adjective+compounds&source=bl&ots=eQK0M41FSe&sig=5p1TwTbUWrL6m1SZvPtz5_2cmz0&hl=en&sa=X&ei=LznlUp22FMWzhAfQ6oC4BA&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=10.2%20adjective%20compounds&f=false) in her book on morphology. Quite a few examples are of participle adjectives. (I added (m) M is the agent of control and H the controlled / enslaved: demon-possessed; menu-driven.)

Comment: @Laure: Maybe it's not *definitive* (what ever is, in such matters?), but it's certainly a pretty *good* answer. You might consider paraphrasing or linking to [John Lawler's comment](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134192/with-without-ed-for-the-compound-adjectives-formed-by-adj-noun#comment277590_134192) on the earlier related SO question (which I'd be more than happy to see closed as a dup of *this* one now, given the calibre of answers we have here from you and Mari-Lou).

Comment: ...essentially, John is explaining why *-ed* gets "lost" in some people's versions of things like *soft-shell[-ed] crab*. Which doesn't explain why a surprising number of people opt for [*candle **light** dinner*](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22candle+light+dinner%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1), but it's all interesting stuff.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I've added link to John Lawler's comment. Do rectify my answer if you think I haven't done it properly. Thanks for directing me to this most interesting comment.

Comment: @Laure: The only thing I can find to carp about now is your very first line! Okay, I eyeballed it carelessly first time around, but so far as I'm concerned *in toto* this answer is immeasurably more "definite/definitive" than the average on ELU. You've been on the site quite a while - obviously hiding your light under a bushel, to some extent. It amuses me greatly that [your much earlier answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/52103/2637) to a question we "collaboratively" addressed also cites a **French** paper ([*Plus ça change*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/plus_%C3%A7a_change), huh? :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I'm not the first here to do errors and I'm certain I won't be the last. I don't mind at all my posts being edited. Done! Well, I like sharing what I know most about: English and French. I think it's unfortunate English people have forgotten a lot of them had ancestors whose mother tongue was Old French! By the way of all the answers I've posted my favourite is not the one you're linking too (I'd forgotten about it), but that [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/142955/where-does-english-get-the-word-condom-from) ; it really took me a lot of research and reading.

Comment: @Laure: I must have missed that one back when it was posted. Have a belated upvote!

Answer (score 3):

Adjectives that precede nouns are called *attributive adjectives* e.g., *an **angry** man*. Adjectives ending in -ed or -ing are called [*participial adjectives*](http://grammar.about.com/od/pq/g/Participial-Adjective.htm)  because they have the same endings as verb participles. However, not all participial adjectives end with *-ed* (past participle) and *-ing* (present participle), if a compound adjective contains an irregular verb than it will take the past participle ending.

> a *hand-written* letter
>   a *candle-lit* dinner
>   an *easily-misunderstood* question
>   a *built-up* area

Often a compound adjective is written with a hyphen, especially if it precedes the noun. Many participial adjectives have no corresponding verb, in which case they are formed by combining a noun with a participle:

> alcohol-based chemicals
>   battle-hardened soldiers
>   a tree-lined avenue
>   a short-handed team
>   a **short-tempered** man
>   a kind-hearted girl

Compounds formed by a noun ending with *-ed* are hyphenated in any position in the sentence hence, the first example could be rewritten as *"chemicals that are alcohol-based"* likewise *"a short-tempered man"* and *"a man who is short-tempered"*. But in the case of

> a man with a short temper

in this phrase, there is no compound adjective, *short* is an attributive adjective qualifying the noun, temper. Consequently, many of the given examples can also be rewritten without using a compound adjective and a hyphen.

- *a dinner lit by candle*
- *a question that is easily misunderstood*
- *a letter written by hand*
- *a girl with a kind heart*

More information, for those interested, on compound adjectives see this [page](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tcdnstyl-chap?lang=fra&lettr=chapsect2&info0=2.04).

Thanks to @Edwin Ashworth for pointing out that hyphens are necessary to disambiguate meaning thus you can have '*a man-eating shark*' but the phrase, '*a man eating shark*' contains a completely different meaning.

Comment: I'd just add that the hyphen becomes necessary on some occasions, for disambiguation (thus 'a man-eating shark' v 'a man eating shark' for a present-participle compound-adjective example).

Answer (score 2):

"wooded mountains" 
The ending in "wooded" is not the normal ending of verbs as in "open/opened/opened".
When -ed is added to a noun is becomes an adjective meaning having something or being provided  with something. Some examples:
wooded mountains - provided with wood,
snow-capped mountains - provided with caps of snow

This type of word formation was already in use in Latin.
Latin fortuna meaning luck, 
Latin fortunat-us meaning having luck, favoured by luck or the goddess of luck.

Answer (score 0):

There is [an excellent discussion](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=596292) over in the WordReference forums about compound adjectives ending in -ed which ultimately proved inconclusive.  An [earlier question here on SO](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/134192/with-without-ed-for-the-compound-adjectives-formed-by-adj-noun) failed to generate an answer either.  So one reasonable conclusion might simply be "that's how it's done in English," which I find thoroughly disappointing but possibly true.  :-)

Here is [one scholarly article called "Compound adjectives in English: The type lion-hearted and good-natured"](http://cat.inist.fr/?aModele=afficheN&cpsidt=14957298) which seeks to explain the -ed compound adjective type.  This website is a French site, but the original publication is in English, and up was published in an [Italian journal, as you can see in this bibliography](http://books.google.com/books?id=5KXdKLDym2QC&pg=PA245&lpg=PA245&dq=Compound+adjectives+in+English:+The+type+lion-hearted+and+good-natured&source=bl&ots=ixHE0dSEXv&sig=yGRthDyQNHARMwleMKXg5dfXPOQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=BrXkUq-ICYj0oAS9roHYCw&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=Compound%20adjectives%20in%20English%3A%20The%20type%20lion-hearted%20and%20good-natured&f=false).  Unfortunately, I can't find an online copy of the article--yet....

Comment: Thank you for the links! I think I'll just go with the "that's what native English speakers and writers do" excuse.

Comment: You're welcome. :-). (Incidentally, the recommended practice/courtesy is to "accept" an and/or up vote it if you like to.)

Comment: I fail to see the relevance and utility in posting a *French* article link which requires a fee. Did you read it? If so, could you please provide a brief summary?

Comment: Well, linguistic scholars write in many languages.  The article isn't about French compound adjectives.  It's about English compound adjectives, but it's written either in French or English and I can't tell, because the article requires a fee to read.  But the title makes it very clear it is pertinent to the OP's question, so I offered the link in case he/she is interested.  :-)

Comment: Which he has to pay. And do you know if he can speak in French? Do you know if the article is any good? What do you know about it?

Comment: Are you kidding?  I just offered the link because it appears to be relevant.  If

Comment: Are you kidding?  I never claimed I had read the article.  From its title, it appears to pertain to the issue at hand, so I offered the link, with a disclaimer.  Now that I revisit the link, I see it is referenced in both English and French (the title is translated) so I will edit my post to make it clear that it is unclear whether the article is in English or French.

Comment: I did find the real article:  it is in English, but in an Italian journal to which it appears to be hard to gain access.  Nobody is suggesting it is definitive, merely offering it as an avenue for future research should the OP wish to pursue it.

Comment: I just wanted to see if there was a quick answer to my question, so please don't worry about the article! My coworker is a very nice person, but not really nice enough that I'm willing to pay for some research.  (By the way, I tried up voting, but it's telling me I need 15 reputation.  Sorry.  :(  )

Comment: Glad you got the answer you wanted.  Cheers!

Comment: For the record, I did not down-vote your answer.

Comment: For the record, neither did I. But I completely agree Mari-Lou's point that it's not really a good idea to include links in *answers* to paid-for content that even the poster hasn't read (and which may therefore not be endorsed, and in this particular case may not even be in *English*). In the end though, it seems to me this answer adds nothing to the one on the original SO question (which at least has the merit of a couple of salient comments from our resident site pros).

Comment: OK, I see:  instead of answering, put the link in a comment.  I got it.  Thanks.

Comment: @jbeldock: Don't feel too bad! Ironically, the [excellent answer from Kosmonaut](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/2256/2637) (another of our highly-respected resident site pros :) to the "related" question Mari-Lou ferretted out also includes a link that only subscribers to OED can access. But note that he copied the important section of the OED text into his answer ("modified to have less abbreviations", considerate chap that he is! :)

Comment: Yes, agreed.  If I *could* have accessed the link, I would have.  Alas, the French government (believe it or not) turned off the site's ability to serve documents--and, it turns out--the original source was an English-language paper in an Italian journal (merely copied to the French site).  So, in the end, it is "unobtanium" unless one has academic journal access.

Answer (score 0):

-The suffix -ed just makes a new adjective out of a periphrasis (preposition+adjective+noun), allowing you to make your sentences shorter and more elegant. So instead of saying a man **with a kind heart** you say a **kind-hearted** man.